# Does exporting to lossless HEVC prevent loss when re-exporting an already exported video file?

Tags: premiere, compression, export, hevc

Software: After Effects, Premiere Pro

So I had a little bit of trouble with my main PC and can't get it fixed before the deadline of my client. I already had the final video ready and exported before the PC broke down, but the client asked if I could insert something at the beginning and end of the video. I have access to the source/raw files but re-rendering it all would take too long(If it works at all) on my laptop.

If I set it up like [Intro][Original Video][Outro] and exported it in lossless HEVC, will there be a downgrade in quality of the Original Video? Also, does exporting to HEVC lossy but with higher bitrate than the original video help preserve the quality?